# Does a variable always refer to just one of the possible elements in a given set?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

For example, if $x$ is an element of $S$, such that $x$ is a natural number greater than $5$, the possible values of $x$ are many, but does $x$ refer to only one of those possible values?

Comment: At a given "time", yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the statement, "Let $S = \{n\in\Bbb N~:~n\geq 5\}$ and let $x\in S$" then $x$ is an arbitrary single element of $S$.  An element may only be one value at any given time.  Although we do not know much information about $x$ other than the fact that it is an element of $S$, we are able to learn things about it, for example that $x! > 2^x$.  Such statements we can prove to be true *regardless* which exact value $x$ has.

If we were able to prove things about $x$ using only the knowledge that we are given and nothing more, then despite $x$ at the time only having been one value, since $x$ is arbitrary the argument works regardless what the value of $x$ was and so we can successfully prove things about *every* element of $S$ simultaneously with a single argument rather than multiple separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's something like the idea of common nouns in normal language use. Such nouns as man, country, plant, etc., refer to any one of a class of objects. Thus, they're like the variables of mathematics.

Comment: It is more like a *pronoun* : "$x$ is odd" works like "it is odd".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Depends how you interpret it. You could also say *$x$ is an odd number,* which is closer to the set idea.

Comment: Thanks. If the noun/pronoun is a plural, is it like having multiple variables or one variable that refers to a set with more than one member?

Comment: @csp2018 The former. If you say, for example, that all men are mortal. Then you're asserting that a certain variable (man, men, whatever) has a certain property. But you shouldn't push the analogy too far.